# "just my luck!" vs "it's/that's the story of my life"

Tags: idioms

Are there any differences in the meaning of or when we use the idioms '***just my luck!***' and '***it's/that's the story of my life***'? The definitions in the Cambridge Dictionary are:

- just my luck!: something that you say when something bad happens to
  you
- it's/that's the story of my life: said when something bad happens to you that has happened to you many times before

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in the general meaning or the appropriateness for different occasions.

*Just my luck* - That's typical of the bad luck I often have.

*It's the story of my life* - Things like that often happen to me.